# initMetaData(this) Error with Bing Satellite View in OSMDroid

Tags: android, osmdroid, bing-maps

I want to display Satellite Tiles from Bing in OSMDroid and have 'osmdroid-third-party-4.3.jar' installed.

The following code is posted over the web to display the Satellite Tiles, but I get always the Error:

> 'The method initMetaData() in the type BingMapTileSource is not applicable for the arguments' !

```
/* BING SATELLITE VIEW */
        try{
            BingMapTileSource.initMetaData(this);
          String m_locale =   Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();
          BingMapTileSource bing = new BingMapTileSource(m_locale);
          bing.setStyle(BingMapTileSource.IMAGERYSET_AERIAL);
          mapView.setTileSource(bing);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Without the Argument 'this' I get the Error:

> 'The method initMetaData() from the type BingMapTileSource is not visible'

Any Ideas?

Comment: A different try was to add the libraries itself from http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-third-party/src/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/?r=959#tileprovider%2Ftilesource%2Fbing and set the method initMetaData() to public, without any result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First answer wrong.

**updated 22.07.2015**

**How to add Bing maps to osmdroid**

Here are step by step instructions. Perhaps someone this will save a lot of time.

1.Add dependency to gradle

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1'
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.3'
```

2.add library **osmdroid-third-party** [from here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osmdroid/osmdroid-third-party)

**OR**

add three classes in our project (**BingMapTileSource.java, ImageryMetaData.java, ImageryMetaDataResource.java**). [from here](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/osmdroid-third-party/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/bing)

3.Getting a Bing Maps Key. [Instructions here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx)

4.Add the Bing Maps Key to the manifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="BING_KEY" android:value="ApEqyap8rTa4WTNCNv-3pAGQc7XUsHS6595tuDI3MHR59QlahJ5bqYGYhMYJq6Ae" />
```

5.The last step. Add map code

```
        ResourceProxyImpl mResourceProxy = new ResourceProxyImpl(getContext().getApplicationContext());
        MapView mMapView = new MapView(getContext(), 256, mResourceProxy);
        mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        try{
            BingMapTileSource.retrieveBingKey(getContext());
            String m_locale =   Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();
            BingMapTileSource bing = new BingMapTileSource(m_locale);
            bing.setStyle(BingMapTileSource.IMAGERYSET_AERIAL);
            mMapView.setTileSource(bing);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mapContent.addView(mMapView);
```

Comment: Works for me! Thanks for guiding!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by including the right 'BingMapTileSource.java' !

[Here](http://osmdroid.googlecode.com/svn-history/r948/trunk/osmdroid-third-party/src/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/bing/BingMapTileSource.java) you can find a version with a public method initMetaData()